# Polymorphic Association: Create document form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I need your help!

When a user creates a new document, he should assign it to a project or task.

If a user is currently selecting a project the id will not be saved in documentable_id only the documentable_type, but with tasks works perfectly.

Where is my mistake?

**Document.rb**

```
belongs_to :documentable, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :task
```

**Project.rb**

```
has_many :documents, :as => :documentable
```

**Task.rb**

```
has_many :documents, :as => :documentable
```

**documents_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @document = Document.new(document_params)
  @document.user_id = current_user.id
  if @document.save
    redirect_to @document
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
def document_params
  params.require(:document).permit(:attachment, :is_unlocked, :is_paid, :brutto, :netto, :has_skonto, :supplier_id, :due_at, :tax, :number, :documentable_id, :documentable_type)
end
```

**documents/_form.html.erb**

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_select :documentable_id, Project.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Projekt zuordnen"} %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_select :documentable_id, Task.all, :id, :id, { prompt: "Aufgabe zuordnen"} %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 dropdowns with the same name, only the second one will be included in the params.  A rails feature that is useful for some things.

You can add the dropdowns or enable/disable them dynamically to get around this.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Enable/disable with javascript or there is such a feature in rails?